# Overwriting files in python

Tags: python, windows, file-rename

I know there are few threads already for the problem, but I couldnt resolve my problem. Any help will be appreciated.
I have set of files which has be replaced by the starting word.But I get this error everytime I use os.rename().I even tried using shutil.move().But it does not work

```py
for f in os.listdir(p):
    path, filename = os.path.split(f)
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    start, *rest = file_name.rsplit("_",1)
    new_filename = '_'.join(start.split('_')[:-3])
    #print(new_filename)
    old_file = os.path.join(path,file_name)
    new_file = os.path.join(path,new_filename)
    #print(old_file)
    print(new_file)

    try:
        os.rename(old_file, new_file)
    except WindowsError:
        os.remove(new_file)
        os.rename(old_file, new_file)


FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the specified file: '1212_seg01_src13_cam01_meas' -> '1212' 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/temp/mptAlgorithm2dPython_vc141_0.0.1_mtu/datapreprocessing.py", line 23, in <module>
    os.remove(new_file)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access denied: '1212'
```

Comment: It looks like a permissions issue. Have you checked the permissions of the directory from where you are trying to delete the file ?

Comment: print file + path, check file is there, check file permissions.

Comment: You didn't append the extension to your filename, so of course it doesn't exist.

Comment: The permissions seems to be fine

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I dont understand by extension?.It is in the form of .tif file.Do i need to add it to the new file?

Comment: You removed the extension in `file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)`, then concatenated the path and filename without extension in `old_file = os.path.join(path,file_name)`. So, `old_file` is the original file name, with complete path, but without the extension (the '.xxx' at the end of the filename). And it doesn't exist.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I tried replacing by old_file = os.path.join(path,f).It takes the full file. Still it gives the same error

Comment: `path, filename = os.path.split(f)` makes no sense. `f` is just a name in the directory listing. It has no path. The path to it is `p`.